# What did Mersault mean?

Tags: camus

In the book "A happy Death"  by "Albert Camus" , what did Mersault mean when he said, 'When I look at my life and its secret colors, I feel like bursting into tears' ?

Comment: See [A Happy Death : Summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Happy_Death).

Comment: IMO, nothing specifically "philosophical"... Mersault expresses a sort of astonishment for the "variety" of life.

Comment: Mersault is also the title character of Camus' novel [L’Étranger  (1942)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stranger_(Camus_novel)). There are common themes with the novel *La mort heureuse* (written between 1936 and 1938 but unpublished during Camus life).

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer, despite not having read the novel, so apologies in advance! I'd guess that 'colour' is a [metaphor](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaphor/) that compares Mersault's interior life to colour, with the ground, point of comparison, being how both (colour and his ambitions etc.) add something: life's choices are not monochrome like.

> [Life](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/camus/) is no one single, simple thing, but a series of tensions and
>   dilemmas.

And perhaps, by calling them "secret", Mersault is claiming that his dilemmas are *only his*

The phrase "bursting into tears" is often used when happy ("I was so happy I burst into tears" is common), so it's ambiguous at least out of context whether he's sad.

> [The existentialist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Happy_Death) topic of the book is the "will to happiness," the
>   conscious creation of one's happiness, and the need of time (and
>   money) to do so.

Comment: i'll just delete it if not informed enough to answer

Comment: But why he is happy after seeing life's tensions and dilemma's

Comment: @DikshitGautam i've not read the book, but your question reminds of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Myth_of_Sisyphus)