# What do philosophers think about colors?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Colors seem to signify some philosophy. For example black roughly stands for death and mourning in many cultures. White on the other hand, roughly stands for purity.

There is long list of colors and their meaning differs from culture to culture,but I am interested in what do philosophers think about colors and their meaning?
For example - What do philosophers think about Orange ? There was a web series named ,“Orange is the new Black”.
What do philosophers think about “Orange is the new Black” means ?
What “Truth” does color possibly convey other than the color itself?
Is there some kind of war or competition or cooperation between colors?

Comment: i remember [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/59166/what-did-mersault-mean). find it strange, the "white karma" 'white as sincerity' thing

Comment: Philosophers try to spend as much time as possible in those vivid pink rooms.